# take laravel DB row's with condition

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, laravel

I have a table named `advertises` and I want to get row's of that table in random order and only take `1` each time. I know it can be done with query in controller with something like this:

```
$advertises = Advertise::inRandomOrder()->take(1);
```

But what I really want to ask is how can I make query to show this in certain place like let say second paragraph of my posts?

Here is an example in `WordPress` that would do that but I need to know if it's possible to be done in laravel as well or not:

```
<?php

//Insert ads after second paragraph of single post content.

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post_ads' );

function prefix_insert_post_ads( $content ) {

    $ad_code = '<div>Ads code goes here</div>';

    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $ad_code, 2, $content );
    }

    return $content;
}

// Parent Function that makes the magic happen

function prefix_insert_after_paragraph( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {

        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Single Post view:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                            <div class="single-blog blog-details two-column">
                                <div class="post-thumb">
                                    <img src="{{ url('images/') }}/{{ $post->image }}" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height:auto; max-height:500px;" alt="{{ $post->title }}">
                                    <div class="post-overlay">
                                        <span class="uppercase"><a href="#">{{$post->created_at->format('d')}} <br><small>{{$post->created_at->format('M')}}</small></a></span>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="post-content overflow">
                                    <div class="bodytext">{!!  $post->body !!}</div>
                                    <div class="post-bottom overflow">
                                      @role('Admin')
                                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['posts.destroy', $post->id] ]) !!}
                                        @can('Edit Post')
                                        <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a>
                                        @endcan
                                        @can('Delete Post')
                                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                                        @endcan
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                      @endrole
                                      @role('Editor')
                                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['posts.destroy', $post->id] ]) !!}
                                        <a href="{{ url()->previous() }}" class="btn btn-primary">Back</a>
                                        @can('Edit Post')
                                        <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Edit</a>
                                        @endcan
                                        @can('Delete Post')
                                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']) !!}
                                        @endcan
                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                      @endrole
                                      <h3>Share this article:</h3>
                                      <div class="sharethis-inline-share-buttons"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="author-profile padding">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-2">
                                                <img src="images/blogdetails/1.png" alt="">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                                <h3>Rodrix Hasel</h3>
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliq Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi</p>
                                                <span>Website:<a href="www.jooomshaper.com"> www.jooomshaper.com</a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="response-area">
                                    <h2 class="bold">Comments</h2>
                                </div><!--/Response-area-->
                                @include('parts/comments')
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: I Laravel you use views and just insert like normal html. If I understand you correctly you would like to display an advertisement in the same place of the site, but it should be a random advertisement, right?

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle yes.

Comment: Could you post your blade template file, please.

Comment: Take the advert and pass it to the view.

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle My blade is empty yet cause no have the function that i need yet! my blade would be my `post-single.blade.php` and all the elements of posts like `title, image,body etc.` cause i want to show ads in my `{{$post->body}}`

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi That I know! what I want is to show it in second paragraph of my `$post->body` please read the question.

Comment: can you paste your view, I mean the part related to your description?

Comment: If you want to do that, I think you would have to insert a placeholder into the body and replace it after retrieving the post and the advertisement. I would do it like that...

Comment: The function you have from WP is not the way to do it anyway...

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Updated.

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle Ok can you give me sample of your idea? so i can try it? PS: I know WP sample wont work in laravel that was just an example of possibility.

Comment: Oh, is it not always you who are writing the posts?

Comment: You can set your advertise in a hidden div in the view and put it inside the $post->body later using JS

Comment: Yeah, actually come to think of it, I would load it via Ajax, when the page has finished loading and insert i with jQuery

Comment: @would you give me example of that? `code`

Comment: @UlrikMcArdle `Oh, is it not always you who are writing the posts?` what does that mean?! :|

Comment: Never mind, see my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (not testet and should maybe be modified a little:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get('/widget/random-advertisement', function(data){
            $('<div class="advertisement">'+data+'</div>').insertAfter('#your-post p');
        }, 'html');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't get this part `/widget/random-advertisement` what does that do?

Comment: That is your URL, create an endpoint for that in the routes file (<5.4 routes.php || >5.4 routes/web.php) and return a fully rendered view of the advertisement.